# Django: Limit to size of database-backed sessions?

Tags: django, session

Django's documentation ([here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/#using-cookie-based-sessions)) state that cookie-based sessions can exceed the 'standard' of 4096 bytes per cookies.

What about [database-backed sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/http/sessions/#using-database-backed-sessions), is there a limit to the amount of data that can be stored in the session?  I didn't see anything in the documentation, nor on SO.

For my project, I'll need to save ~50KB to a user's database-backed session.  Let me know if you need more info.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The database backend stores the session data in a [`TextField`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/contrib/sessions/base_session.py#L28) in the database.

The size limit of this field depends on your database backend, e.g., for Postgres (stored as `text`) it [is unlimited](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-character.html), and for MySQL (stored as `longtext`) it is approximately [4GB](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-type-overview.html).

Either way the limit is going to be far higher than ~50KB!